# AWS SES Emails being silently blocked by outlook, hotmail

Tags: outlook, amazon-ses, hotmail

We use amazon SES to send account confirmation emails to our users. Our users are registered with our service by their district; while they are rightful recipients of our signup emails (their district has registered them) they are not always aware of this before hand.

Presently, it appears that none of our emails are reaching users with outlook or hotmail email accounts. They are not bouncing, just silently being blocked. We cannot for the life of us determine how to get this solved; we cannot find a support  at microsoft to ask.

What can we do to stop our emails from being silently rejected by these servers? Who can we contact to fix this?

Comment: Any update for this issue?

Comment: No, still searching.

Comment: anythung? I'm not even getting any bounces to the emails

Comment: Any update on this issue @mtro? I am having this same issue and not even getting bounces.

Comment: I've had no updates. We solved it with DKIM and SPF configuration

Comment: You ever figure this out? It's happening to us right now as well despite configuring our SPF record. :/